# 'NODE_PATH' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows, reactjs, npm

I have cloned a repo of react js from github, and installed node in C:/Program Files/. When I run npm start command from project directory. I get 'NODE_PATH' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. error.
I tried a lot to set up environment by different commands but not able to start project. I am using windows 10 and my script portion of package.json looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_PATH=./src node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "NODE_PATH=./src node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "NODE_PATH=./src node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
```

Comment: I have changed script to following:
 "scripts" : "node server.js"

Answer (score 8):

Using cross-env is the solution. Read more [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env).

Install cross-env:

```
npm install cross-env
```

You should update to:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "cross-env NODE_PATH=./src node scripts/start.js",
  "build": "cross-env NODE_PATH=./src node scripts/build.js",
  "test": "cross-env NODE_PATH=./src node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom",
  "predeploy": "npm run build",
  "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately I got the solution. Just two steps to follow:
Replace first line in Script tag in package.json from following
"start": "node scripts/start.js",

Add following in .env file:
NODE_PATH=./src

Restart cmd and run npm start.