# How to use import with absolute paths in Cypress tests built with ParcelJS?

Tags: cypress, parceljs

I'm using imports with absolute paths in my Parcel project but these absolute paths aren't equally resolved by Cypress tests.

### Difference in module resolution

**Parcel**: `import {foo} from '/foo.js'`: relatively to project root

**Cypress**: `import {foo} from '/foo.js'`: absolute on disk root

When Parcel's entry point is in `src` folder importing `/foo.js` anywhere in the project looks for file in path `<project>/src/foo.js`. (Docs: https://parceljs.org/module_resolution.html#absolute-paths)

But Cypress doesn't have any *entry point* and if it tries to import a file using absolute path it considers `/` as a *filesystem root*. This can happen when imported file (*foo.js*) internally imports another file (*bar.js*).

### Example

*cypress-test.js*

```
import {foo} from '../../src/foo.js' // I don't care using relative paths in tests.
// tests here...
```

*foo.js*

```
import {bar} from '/bar.js' // Absolute path not found by Cypress
//...
```

How can I make Cypress to resolve absolute paths relative to some entry point as Parcel does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compile your spec files yourself, changing path resolution.

For that, you can use a Cypress' official [browserify preprocessor](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-browserify-preprocessor), and adding `paths` [browserify option](https://github.com/browserify/browserify#browserifyfiles--opts), and also [pathmodify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pathmodify) browserify plugin that will take care of stripping the leading `/` in paths, so that the path resolution works correctly.

First, install the packages by:

```
npm install -D @cypress/browserify-preprocessor pathmodify
```

Then in your `cypress/plugins/index.js`:

```js
const preprocessor = require('@cypress/browserify-preprocessor');
const pathmodify = require('pathmodify');

const browserifyOptions = preprocessor.defaultOptions.browserifyOptions;

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// (1) resolve paths relative to project root
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

browserifyOptions.paths = [
  // the process.cwd() depends on the cypress process being started from
  //  the project root. You can also use an absolute path here.
  require('path').resolve( process.cwd() )
];

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// (2) regard paths starting with `/` as project-relative paths
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

browserifyOptions.plugin = browserifyOptions.plugin || [];
browserifyOptions.plugin.unshift([
  pathmodify, { mods: [
    // strip leading `/` when resolving paths
    pathmodify.mod.re(/^\//, '')
  ]}
]);

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// (3) compile spec files when they're run
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

const compileFile = preprocessor( preprocessor.defaultOptions );

module.exports = ( on ) => {
  on('file:preprocessor', file => {
    return compileFile( file );
  });
}
```

Learn more at https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/preprocessors-api.html

Comment: Although @dwelle solution fixes the problem when resolving files for Cypress it creates the same problem for Parcel.
For Parcel `/` means _project-root_. If I omit `/` Parcel resolves the file path relatively to current file.

Comment: Yea, but you're compiling cypress specs only, no? How does Parcel come into it? You should keep compiling your app with parcel, and use whatever paths you want there, and in cypress specs you'll simply not write the initial `/`. Otherwise I dunno what the problem is about.

Comment: Problem is when file imported within Cypress test internally imports another file (with `/`). Sorry, I'll make that more clear in the question.

Comment: Right, that didn't occur to me :facepalm:. Alright, lemme think

Comment: Stripping the first `/` in a `@cypress/browserify-preprocessor` plugin works. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201566/discussion-between-pedro-and-dwelle).