# Cypress: How can I use absolute path to outside files in cypress folder?

Tags: typescript, cypress

**Context**

I'm using Typescript + React + Cypress and folder structure is like this.

```
cypress/
  tsconfig.json
src/
tsconfig.json
```

I can use absolute path in `src` folder like `utils/sort.ts` because `baseUrl` in `tsconfig.json` is `src`. However, I cannot use absolute path in `cypress` folder which is referencing functions in `src` folder.

**Expected Behavior**

```js
import { convertDate } from 'src/utils';
import { waitTest } from 'utils';

....
```

**Current Behavior**

```js
import { convertDate } from 'src/utils'; // Error (absolute path for "src" folder)
import { waitTest } from 'utils'; (absolute path for "cypress" folder)

....
```

How can I achieve this? I wanna to set `baseUrl` of `cypress` folder to `src` which is outside `cypress`. Current `baseUrl` of `tsconfig.json` in cypress is `.` which refers `cypress` folder.

Comment: Why must it be absolute and not `../src/utils`?

Comment: @SteveZodiac Because relative path is not straightforward. One depth like `../` is simple example, but worst case would be `../../../../src`.

Comment: Hm, well your example is not reflecting your problem.

Comment: Maybe you have to read this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58592497/how-to-use-import-with-absolute-paths-in-cypress-tests-built-with-parceljs)