# How can I run Cypress tests in a Docker container where the test files are a volume mount?

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, cypress

### Background

I am trying to use Docker in my CI process with multiple projects and do not want to have to rebuild the image every run as the tests belong to the project, not the image.

### Problem

If I try the following:

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM cypress/included:cypress-12.5.1-node-16.18.1-chrome-109.0.5414.74-1-ff-109.0-edge-109.0.1518.52-1

RUN mkdir /e2e-test
WORKDIR /e2e-test

RUN export NODE_PATH=$(npm root -g)

RUN npm install -g axe-core
RUN npm install -g cypress-axe
RUN npm install -g base64url
RUN npm install -g moment
RUN npm install -g dayjs
RUN npm install -g cypress-fail-fast 

ENTRYPOINT ["npm"]
```

#### Command

```bash
docker run -it -v //c/_projects/my-application/tests:/e2e-test -w /e2e-test cypress-test-browser run test
```

#### Error

```bash
Oops...we found an error preparing this test file:

  > cypress/support/e2e.js

The error was:

Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./cypress/support/api-commands.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'base64url' in '/e2e-test/cypress/support'
resolve 'base64url' in '/e2e-test/cypress/support'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /e2e-test/package.json (relative path: ./cypress/support)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration        
    Looked for and couldn't find the file at the following paths: or is not a directory
[/e2e-test/cypress/support/node_modules]
[/e2e-test/cypress/node_modules]
[/e2e-test/node_modules]
[/node_modules]
 @ ./cypress/support/api-commands.js 5:18-38
 @ ./cypress/support/e2e.js
 @ multi ./cypress/support/e2e.js
```

So Cypress cannot see the globally imported modules. I followed the advice in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53872507/1003830), and added the `NODE_PATH` to my test command in `packages.json` and that did not work either.

### Other approaches tried

#### Using local modules

I tried copying a `packages.json` file to the Docker image and using `npm install` to bring those dependencies in locally. However, when I mount the project directory to the container it overwrites that directory and hides the `node_modules` directory.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?